# fuel consumption worse with rebuilt engine

Tags: gasoline, ram, motors, mileage

I recently had to replace my motor in my 2013 dodge ram 1500 sport. they put in a rebuilt motor and i have noticed I am having a hard time with fuel mileage, on my motor that came with the ram I could keep the fuel consumption at 13L per 100km, with the new rebuilt motor I am having a hard time getting it below 18L per 100km. No idea whats going on. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Was the replacement engine the exact same as the original in specification? Did they put the same transmission back in?

Comment: Has the engine been run in? And had an oil change/ service since being refitted?

Comment: Did you change tire size about then as well or anything else on the drive train?

Comment: lots of parts on the engine have probably not been replaced with new ones,like the injectors and other external parts on the engine.

Comment: no the engine has not had time to be run in yet... and it is all a rebuilt motor to the same as my previous motor, no tire size change and everything stayed the same except my motor being replaced by a exact rebuilt engine as to my old one. im clueless on why its costing more in gas

Comment: Give it a few thousand miles for break in, then change the oil. recheck mileage. reman engines have a slightly larger displacement due to oversize pistons, this can affect mileage slightly also, but not that much. More than likely it needs to be broken in as suggested.